# How to only leave in given characters in a file?

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, tr

Purpose:

```
tr -cd '\12\40-\176'
```

but with accents, ex.: á, í, ű, ő, ö, ü, ű, ú, ó, é.

In octal:

```
"á" is 341
"\n" is 12
```

So I tried:

```
[user@notebook ~]$ printf 'XXXá\nXXX' | tr -cd '\12\341' | cat -vte -
$
[user@notebook ~]$
```

**Question**: Why doesn't tr leaves "á" in the output? Maybe it doesn't knows the extended ASCII table chars or what?

**UPDATE:**

```
[user@notebook small]$ printf 'árvíztűrő tükörf\túrógép\n' | strings -eS -n1
árvíztűrő tükörf    úrógép
[user@notebook small]$
```

The tab is unneeded, but string leaves it in.

UPDATE#2:

```
[user@notebook ~]$ locale -a | grep hu_HU.utf8
hu_HU.utf8
[user@notebook ~]$ printf 'someárvíztűrő tükörf\túrógép\ntext' | LANG=hu_HU.utf8 sed 's/[\d128-\d255]//g;s/[\d000-\d031]//g' | cat -vte -
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: Invalid collation character
[user@notebook ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "á" is 341

No, it isn't. Your character set is UTF-8, in which á is character U+00E1 which is encoded as the two-byte sequence `\xc3\xa1` = `\303\241`. When you write `\341` in the argument to `tr`, it's interpreted as the byte `\341`.

> it doesn't knows the extended ASCII table chars

Yes, it does — except that there's no such thing as “extended ASCII table chars”: ASCII is a 7-bit character set. You meant character sets that extend ASCII, and `tr` does support them. `tr` processes characters according to the current locale, or bytes.

`tr -cd '\12\40-\176'` in ASCII means to retain printable characters and newlines. In any locale, you can say “printable characters” as `[:print:]`. `\n` is a clearer way of denoting newlines. Thus:

```
tr -cd '\n[:print:]'
```

Unfortunately, some implementations of `tr` (including the GNU version) can't cope with character sets in UTF-8. You can use sed instead.

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strings` e.g.

```
$ printf 'XXXhelloá\nYYY' | strings -es -n1
XXXhello
YYY
```

strings has various options (`man strings` for details) for extracting text (including, with -es, only 7-bit characters) from an input string or file.

If you want to exclude more 'special' characters you can use sed:

```
# printf 'someárvíztűrő tükörf\túrógép\ntext' | LANG=C sed 's/[\d128-\d255]//g;s/[\d000-\d031]//g' | cat -vte -
somervztr tkrfrgp$
text$
```

If you want to combine text on one line just pipe the text through xargs, this substitutes a space for any line feeds:

```
$ printf 'someárvíztűrő tükörf\túrógép\ntext' | xargs | LANG=C sed 's/[\d128-\d255]//g;s/[\d000-\d031]//g;s/\n//g' | cat -vte -
somervztr tkrf rgp text$
```

Comment: Many thanks, but I updated the question

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: It gives "Invalid collation character" when I tried to use "á" in sed.

Comment: You need to use the correct LANG setting to overcome this, this is why I put 'LANG=C'. You can show the locales available on your system with `locale -a`. Try some!

Comment: I tried, thanks, but something still missing :\

Comment: you need to use a non-UTF8 locale, you are using a UTF8 locale that is why you get the collation problem